# Adding foreign key constraints to existing columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a database that has gone through some major transformations over several years of having input from several different coders. Some of the tables contain references to other data through a reference column, but do not have foreign key constraints. Meaning that there are some tables that may contain dead links.

I would like to add foreign key constraints to all the reference columns. How can I ensure that this would be successful when some data may be referencing dead links and others may actually be null.

I think I need to say something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Persons FOREIGN KEY
(
    Person_ID --In some cases Person_ID will be null
) REFERENCES dbo.People
(
    Person_ID
) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
ON DELETE  NO ACTION 
NOT FOR REPLICATION

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users
    NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Persons
GO
COMMIT
```

Please let me know if this is accurate and also if there are any hidden pitfalls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haha! thanks! I will. (the elipses at the end of your comment scares me). So if there are no issues it's fine, but what do I do if there are issues? Does this mean there is no way of adding a foreign key constraint?

Comment: Ok thanks for the input. Hopefully there aren't too many issues as there are 29000 users and I need to add foreign key constraints to around 40 tables!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Just try it!!** If there is a problem - a value that doesn't exist in the referenced table - SQL Server will tell you, and nothing bad will happen - trust me! :-)

Seriously: if there are issues, e.g. rows in `Users` that have invalid `Person_ID` values, then SQL Server will **not** create the FK constraint - as simple as that.

In that case, if you do have entries in the `Users` table that do not reference a valid `Person_ID` in the `Person` table - you will need to fix these first. Either set them to `NULL` (if you cannot figure out what person they reference), or setting them to a valid `Person_ID` - and then try to add your FK constraint again.

You can also find those entries before applying the FK constraint with a query something like this:

```
 SELECT (columns)
 FROM dbo.Users
 WHERE Person_ID IS NOT NULL 
 AND Person_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Person_ID FROM dbo.Person)
```

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the query showing how to identify the faulty references.

Comment: hofnarwillie - Did you checked this ? Did it take the foreign key or error was thrown. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. This will show `NULL`s on items that can't join meaning the reference was deleted.